# How we count how many multiple selection in chart area?

Tags: c#, selection, mschart

I want to count the multiple selections in chart area.As an example user can marked multiple selection as this picture,[Multiple selected chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejtNo.png).So how I count how many multiple selection in this chart.This is MSchart in windowsform by using C#.

my multiple selection code as follows;

```
        SizeF rangeOfCurve = SizeF.Empty;
        List<SizeF> ranges = new List<SizeF>();
        List<int> selectedIndices = new List<int>();

      private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
            {

                ranges.Add(rangeOfCurve);
                selectedIndices.Union(collectDataPoints(chart1.Series[0],rangeOfCurve.Width, rangeOfCurve.Height)).Distinct();

                StripLine sl = new StripLine();
                sl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.LightSeaGreen);
                sl.IntervalOffset = Math.Min(rangeOfCurve.Width, rangeOfCurve.Height);
                sl.StripWidth = Math.Abs(rangeOfCurve.Height - rangeOfCurve.Width);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(sl);           

            }
            List<int> collectDataPoints(Series s, double min, double max)
            {
                List<int> hits = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count; i++)
                    if (s.Points[i].XValue >= min && s.Points[i].XValue <= max) hits.Add(i);           
                return hits;
            }

      private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
            {

                rangeOfCurve = new SizeF((float)e.NewSelectionStart, (float)e.NewSelectionEnd);
            }
```

This is my code for export those selected data to new .csv file.In here I added button click event then selected area data to export another .csv file.but I want to say I can add multiple selection in chart area but data is exported only last selected part only.how can I got all multiple selection data.this is code for getting one selected area data to another .csv file.

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     List<Graph> ObservingData = new List<Graph>(); // List to store all available Graph objects from the CSV
     int index = 0;
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\CSVFile\NEWFile\Export\NewFile.csv"))
     {
         // Loops through each lines in the CSV
         foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathToCsv))
         {
             // here line stands for each line in the csv file
             string[] CsvLine = line.Split(',');

             // creating an object of type Graph based on the each csv line
             // and adding them to the  List<Graph>
             Graph Instance1 = new Graph();

             if (index == 0)
             {
                 sw.WriteLine(line);
             }    
             else
             {
                 //Add the code here..**
                  if (((chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart))<=index  && ( index<= (chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd)))
                 {
                     sw.WriteLine(line);
                 }                       
             }
             index++; 
         }
         sw.Close();
     }
     MessageBox.Show("Data are copied to the new .CSV file");
 }
```

If you can give any help to solve this.I am so much thankful to you.

Comment: You can enumerate the StripLines collection and test the properties of each. Do you want info on the stripline (which btw are not really 'selections') or about the DataPoints?

Comment: @TaW.I am beginner for  this language.so please give me a help to solve this.I want to show multiple selection on the chart and I want to get that multi selected data points in .csv file that i had.so I want to count boundaries of every multi selected area.I can get one selected data area by using ' chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart' and 'chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd' but I can not get multi selected area one by one.So please give me a any help for that.

Comment: There can nly be one cursor for an axis and therefore only one selection you can create this way. Striplines are not the easiest way to create a selection, either. - See the link for an example that uses only mouse events to create multiple selections! Feel free to ask if you have questions!

Comment: @TaW thank you for your help.but my question is how I get all selected data between strip-lines  in this chart.please any suggestion what I want to do.

Comment: I can re-open the question but I can't relieve you from deciding on the UI you want.. Have you coded a method to loop over the Stiplines collection? Have you manages to create multiple Striplines with the mouse?

Comment: @TaW.I edited my code.please look at that and give me a solution for that.thank you sir

Comment: As I have told you there is only __one__ Cursor on an axis, which happens to be the last of your selections..! So it makes no sense to use it when doing the export! Instead you should enumerate the Striplines collection, just like I shown you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added `StripLines` to mark selections, here is an example of how you can collect the `DataPoints` from these `StripLines`:

Let's create a `List<>` of point list:

```
selectionPoints = new List<List<DataPoint>>();
```

Now we can collect the `DataPoints` like this:

```
List<List<DataPoint>> GetSelectedPoints(ChartArea ca, Series S)
{
    selectionPoints = new List<List<DataPoint>>();

    foreach (var sl in ca.AxisX.StripLines)
    {
        List<DataPoint> points = new List<DataPoint>();
        points = S.Points.Select(x => x)
                  .Where(x => x.XValue >= sl.IntervalOffset
                           && x.XValue <= (sl.IntervalOffset + sl.StripWidth)).ToList();

        selectionPoints.Add(points);
    }
    return selectionPoints;
}
```

And now we can do things with the `DataPoints` like color them..:

```
foreach (var pointList in selectionPoints)
{
    foreach (var dp in pointList) dp.Color = Color.Red;
}
```

.. or export them:

```
string filePath = "D:\\demo.csv";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var pointList in selectionPoints)
{
    foreach (var dp in pointList)
        sb.Append(dp.XValue + "," + dp.YValues[0] + ";");  // pick your format!
}
File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```